# Guardar o ID do usuário em COOKIES é seguro?

Tags: php, segurança, cookies

Guardar o `ID` do usuário em *Cookies* é seguro, pois é fácil vê-lo pelo navegador. As minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

- Guardar o `ID` do usuário em **Cookies** é seguro?
- Se não for seguro, que método `seguro` posso utilizar?
- Como posso estar utilizando-o em *PHP*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Depedende muito do caso de uso

Contando que o id não seja o critério único de acesso do usuário no sistema, não há problema algum. O próprio Stack Overflow exibe o id do usuário na URL, ou seja, não é um dado confidencial. Você só vai precisar tomar certas medidas para segurança caso em algum momento a sua aplicação precise pegar o id do cookie e enviá-lo para o servidor para buscar alguma informação do usuário.

Exemplo de caso:

1. Você salvou o id do usuário no cookie na página 1
2. Na página 2 você precisa pegar o email do usuário, então passa o id do cookie para o servidor, requisitando o email do usuário

Se for para ser usado dessa forma, está extremamente inseguro, uma vez que qualquer pessoa poderia alterar os próprios cookies para pegar dados de qualquer usuário do seu sistema. Sendo assim, você precisaria de mais um fator de segurança para garantir que apenas o usuário que fez login naquela máquina possa estar fazendo uma busca de dados.

Teremos 2 possíveis soluções para termos um sistema seguro nesse caso:

- No momento que o usuário fizer login, criar um token e armazená-lo atrelado ao id do usuário no seu banco de dados do servidor e no cookie do cliente.
- Salvar o id do usuário na session, e quando o mesmo requisitasse alguma informação, verificar se o id que foi passado é o mesmo que consta na session.

Usando uma das 2 medidas citadas acima você poderia guardar e utilizar de forma segura, não apenas o id, mas diversos dados que lhe sejam conveniente salvar no lado cliente da sua aplicação.

Recomendo que você estude se é realmente necessário usar cookies ou session, e qual a melhor forma de usar. Ambos estão ligados a performance e segurança do seu sistema.

Answer (score 4):

Qualquer dado inserido num cookie fica *visível* ao usuário (se ele souber como acessá-lo, é claro), bem como passivo de ser *alterado* pelo usuário. Assim, dizer se é seguro ou não depende de quais as *consequências* dessa exposição do ID.

Raramente um ID de usuário é secreto, então não vejo muito problema nele ser lido. Mas se em um caso particular isso for um problema, é melhor não enviá-lo ao usuário, guardando-o na sessão por exemplo (melhor opção), ou alternativamente criptografá-lo antes de enviar (pior opção, só use se não tiver alternativa).

Quanto a ser alterado, aí depende de como ele está sendo usado, como já abordado nas demais respostas. Em geral, a alteração pode ser problemática se ela permite a um usuário impersonar outros usuários. Nesse caso, é importante sim evitar essa alteração.

Um método, já citado, é o uso de um ID de sessão ou outro token de acesso, aleatório, que não possa ser "adivinhado" na prática (recomendável, em particular pelo fato da grande maioria das linguagens/frameworks darem suporte a esse método, inclusive o PHP). Outro seria *assinar* o cookie antes de mandá-lo pro cliente (seja usando assinatura digital [assimétrica] ou, mais simples, um HMAC), verificando a assinatura quando recebê-lo de volta. Dessa forma, os dados ainda podem ser lidos pelo usuário, mas qualquer alteração nos mesmos invalidaria a assinatura, fazendo o cookie ser rejeitado pelo servidor. Esse método é útil quando não se pode/não se quer armazenar as sessões no servidor, mas ao mesmo tempo é mais complexo de se implementar corretamente (e mais fácil de cometer erros!), então deixo apenas como alternativa.

Answer (score 3):

#### Não, não é seguro

O *cookie* é uma informação em texto limpo que fica guardada no navegador do usuário, onde não há controle nenhum. Não só é possível ver esse dado mas [também é fácil de alterar](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/cookies-manager-plus/). Se seu sistema confia nesse campo para identificar o usuário logado, basta trocar o id do usuário para se tornar outro usuário, sem passar pela senha.

Método mais seguro é guardar o id do usuário numa [sessão](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php), cujos dados ficam armazenados no servidor, longe da possibilidade de serem alterados pelo usuário.

Para o usuário vai um ID de sessão, aleatório. E por ser aleatório, tentar mexer nesse ID vai com grande probabilidade resultar em uma sessão vazia, e portanto inútil para um usuário malicioso.

Comment: Eu acho que isso varia do projeto e da segurança usada nele. E se o usuário possuir um token de autenticação? E se eu quiser fazer um sistema onde tenha a opção do usuário manter-se logado por um longo período de tempo?

Comment: Vide esse caso por exemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957584/stay-logged-in-best-practices-how-does-a-username-in-the-cookie-make-it-more-se

Comment: Caso seja um token tipo GUID é de boa. Dureza são os tokens gerados com procedimentos aleatórios "caseiros". Para manter o usuário logado mais tempo, de qualquer maneira tem de mexer no tempo de vida do cookie. Então daí, sessões: 1. Usa um GUID aleatório bem testado, já com funcionalidade de cookie; 2. Altera o `Expires` do cookie padrão.

Comment: Exatamente, cookies têm de ser sempre bem planejados, costumam ser uma das principais vulnerabilidades de um sistema atualmente